# Не пересылаются сообщения из одного discord сервера в другой

Tags: python, парсер, бот, discord

Не получается сделать бота который бы парсил сообщения из одного сервера дискорда в другой. Бот парсит сообщения только в консоль , при этом ошибок никаких не выдает. Гуглил и пользовался ChatGPT, не нашел решения своей проблемы, буду благодарен за помощь!

```py
import discum
import requests

# Функция для отправки сообщений
def send_message(target_guild_id, target_channel_id, content):
    url = f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{target_channel_id}/messages"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bot token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    payload = {
        "content": content
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Message sent successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to send message.")

# Конфигурация бота
bot = discum.Client(token="token", log=False)
guild_id = '529643356725444618'
user_id = '260027091398033425'
channel_id = '602129543075069953'

@bot.gateway.command
def helloworld(resp):
    if resp.event.ready_supplemental:
        if 'user' in bot.gateway.session.settings_ready:
            user = bot.gateway.session.user
            print("Logged in as {}#{}".format(user['username'], user['discriminator']))
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        if 'guild_id' in m and m['guild_id'] == guild_id and 'author' in m and m['author']['id'] == user_id:
            guildID = m['guild_id']
            channelID = m['channel_id']
            username = m['author']['username']
            discriminator = m['author']['discriminator']
            content = m['content']
            target_guild_id = '966183386379067442'  # Идентификатор целевого сервера
            target_channel_id = '1104039534657798157'  # Идентификатор канала, на который нужно отправлять сообщения
            if guildID == guild_id and channelID == channel_id:
                # Отправка сообщения на целевой сервер и канал
                send_message(target_guild_id, target_channel_id, f"> guild {guildID} channel {channelID} | {username}#{discriminator}: {content}")

# Запуск бота
bot.gateway.run(auto_reconnect=True)
```